# Oracle application and DB scale out in private cloud

Tags: oracle, cloud-computing, sla, rdbms, scale

I have a client who was looking to migrate their Oracle environment to Amazon - probably Amazon RDS but were unable to get the SLA they wanted from it.

I need to know if deploying something to similar to Amazon RDS for Oracle is possible and what with to make Oracle "elastic" within a Private Cloud.

Does anyone have any experience with fully automated scaling and provisioning of Oracle and its databases?

What specifically from Oracle or other application/Middleware providers are out there that could achieve this?

Comment: Out of interest, how does Oracle licencing work with cloud providers?  i.e.: where you don't necessary know / have control over the number of cores / sockets on your server(s).  Or does the cloud provider wrap this up in their cost to you?  Off topic, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace does [Oracle support on their managed hosting](http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/services/database/oracle/). You would then be able to scale out other services within the same datacenter on their public cloud or an [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) based private cloud.

Full disclosure: I now work at Rackspace and I want you to be successful no matter where you deploy. If another option solution comes up, I'd love to hear about it.